# Is it possible to run ANY application or program with HADOOP YARN?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm studying distributed computing recently and found out Hadoop Yarn is one of them.
So thought if I just establish Hadoop Yarn cluster, then every application will run distributed.

But now someone told me that HADOOP Yarn cannot do anything by itself and need other things like mapreduce, spark, and hbase.

If this is correct, then is that mean only limited tasks can be run with Yarn?
Or can I apply Yarn's distributed computing to all applications I want?

Answer (score 2):

**Hadoop** is the name which refers to the entire system.

**HDFS** is the actual storage system. Think of it as S3 or a distributed Linux filesystem.

**YARN** is a framework for scheduling jobs and allocating resources. It handles these things for you, but you don't interact very much with it.

**Spark** and **MapReduce** are managed by Yarn. With these two, you can actually write your code/applications and give work to the cluster.

**HBase** uses the HDFS storage (with is file based) and provides NoSql storage.

Theoretically you can run more than just Spark and MapReduce on Yarn and you can use something else then Yarn (Kubernetes is in works or supported now). You can even write your own processing tool, queue/resource management system, storage... Hadoop has many pieces which you may use or not, depending on your case. But the majority of Hadoop systems use Yarn and Spark.

If you want to deploy Docker containers for example, just a Kubernetes cluster would be a better choice. If you need batch/real time processing with Spark, use Hadoop.

Comment: YARN can deploy Docker containers too. And Spark works on k8s... What does Hbase have to do with the question?

Comment: Never said they couldn’t. Hbase is part of the question. Not sure about Oozie, Slider...

Comment: Can Hadoop/YARN run any Python program without importing special libraries? I feel the program must be written in map-reduce pattern.

Comment: Hadoop/YARN usually runs MapReduce or Spark jobs, which has a specific format and include specific libraries. What you are looking for is Kubernetes. Note that this is their intended use, although you can make them do other tricks, as @OneCricketeer mentioned

Comment: @Gqqnbig You are looking for Hadoop Streaming, which can be be written in any language and requires no extra libraries on its own, but still requires understanding how MapReduce works. There is at least one Python example on the [official docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html), or you can look into using `mrjob`, however I would still suggest you use PySpark over that. If you literally want to run any general Python code, then yes, a container orchestration platform would be better.

Answer (score 0):

YARN itself is a resource manager. You will need to write code that can be deployed onto those resources, and then that could do anything, given that the nodes running the tasks are themselves capable of running the job. For example, you cannot distribute a Python library without first installing the dependencies for that script. Mesos is a bit more generalized / accessible than YARN, if you want more flexibility for the same affect.

YARN mostly supports running JAR files, shell scripts (at least, from Oozie) or Docker containers can be deployed to it as well (refer Apache docs)

You may also refer to the Apache Slider or Twill projects for more information.